# Mediawiki default admin username/password in Azure

Tags: azure, mediawiki

I've created a Mediawiki site in Windows Azure from the one of the gallery templates. But I've been given no information about what the username/password is for the Administrator, It's probably something obvious but I have no experience with mediawiki. Could someone explain to me what the default username/password are in windows azure for mediawiki?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you created the web site in the gallery you were prompted for the admin password.  It was on page 2 of the wizard, "Configure your app".  It appears they are required fields.  If you don't recall what you entered you can delete that website and create a new one.  I'm assuming since you don't recall the password that you aren't that far along in customizing it or worried about losing any data.

There is another way which requires you to get access to the MySQL database and update the password manually to something you know.

```
UPDATE user SET user_password = MD5( CONCAT( user_id, ‘-’, MD5( ‘NEWPASS‘ ) ) ) WHERE user_id =1
```

Of course set NEWPASS to something you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

The default user name in an Azure MediaWiki install is WikiSysop, you had to provide a password as part of the app creation process.